# Display a component view into a module, in Joomla 1.5

Tags: module, components, joomla1.5

I need to display a component view into a module. 
I have developed my own module in which I have put an iframe searching for the view.
It works when I use the default "format" variable in the url ("format=html")

```
<iframe src="index.php?option=com_componentname&view=componentview">
```

but this displays the full page, with header, menus, etc. I have tried to add "format=raw" to the url

```
<iframe src="index.php?option=com_componentname&view=componentview&format=raw">
```

but it doesn't work. I always get a blank page

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this -

```
index.php?option=com_componentname&view=componentview&tmpl=component
```

Comment: I also want to add, to complete the answer that when using "format=raw" i got a blank page due to a bug in Joomla 1.5. Here is the explanation on how to fix this bug:                     http://www.joomlapolis.com/forum/96-maybe-a-problem-with-101/100558-error-msg-on-paypal-payment-callback#104193